# Deploy express server that serves react behind nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

I have an express server on an ec2 instance that has an api (`/api`) and a client (everything that's not `/api` handled in react.)

Goging to `http://ip.address:3000` works fine. It shows the app and everything works.

However going to `https://ip.address` (forwarded by nginx) doesn't work fine. It loads my index.html correctly but 404s on all the `/static/bundle.js` and `/static/bundle.css` files.

nginx

```
    # redirect to node for the dynamic stuff
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8003/index.html;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }
```

express

```
let router: express.Router = express.Router();
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/build")));

const api: ApiRouter.Api = new ApiRouter.Api();
router.use("/api", api.router.bind(api.router));

//Catch all for react - client side routing
router.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/build/index.html"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tell Nginx to

`proxy_pass https://localhost:8003/index.html;`

Then every request which matches that location block will have the matching part of its URL path replaced with whatever path you have added to your proxy_pass URL.

Your location block is simply `/` So if I request `www.yoursite.com/static/bundle.js` then Nginx will match the first `/`, replace it with your path and add the rest. So it will try and serve `www.yoursite.com/index.htmlstatic/bundle.js`

You should proxy /api through Nginx too, and if the static files are coming from an upstream proxy you should enable proxy caching within Nginx too

Comment: But going to https://ip.address/api works just not the static content. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing your full Nginx config. Do you have another location block for `/api` ? What other directives do you have? What ports is it listening on etc etc